# WordPress - Reply on comments with rest API using version 2

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

How do I send reply comment on a comment with WordPress rest API of version 2?

I did a lot of search about WordPress rest API of version 2 but I didn't find a proper solution on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WordPress a "reply" is a comment with a parent ID.

You could add argument "parent" to the comment request.

If comment is a reply, you just send the comment with the argument "parent" in request. The parent is the ID of the comment replied on.

In [example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment) of insert comment in docs, comment parent is 0 becuse it is the main comment. To insert a reply - you add the id of comment replied on as parent id.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment

Comment: thanks for your kind help..its working for me..thank you so much